# How to check While loop "condition" inside its body after each line of code?

Tags: c, data-structures, while-loop, pic18

Here is an example of my code i can place if condition to check While condition flag and put break after each line of the body but it increase overhead. WHAT SHOULD I DO??????

```
  while(!((kvp < (Motor_pos+2)) && (kvp > (Motor_pos-2))) ){
               
                if ( (kvp > (Motor_pos+2))){
//                    Relay_75  = LOW;
                    while (kvp > (Motor_pos+2)) {
                        VAR_CW  = HIGH;    // M1 - Red LED
                        VAR_CCW = LOW;    // M2 - Orange LED
                        for(uint8_t i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
                            ADC_s = ADC_s + Read_VAR();
                        }
                        Motor_pos = ADC_sum/5;
                        ADC_sum =0;
//                        UART_Write( Motor_pos);
                        __delay_ms(50);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if ((kvp < (Motor_pos-2))){
//                    Relay_100  = LOW;
                    while (kvp < (Motor_pos-2)) {
                        VAR_CW = LOW;   // M1 - Red LED
                        VAR_CCW = HIGH;  // M2 - Orange LED
                        for(uint8_t i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
                            ADC_s = ADC_s + Read_VAR();
                        }
                        Motor_pos = ADC_s/5;
                        ADC_s =0;
//                        UART_Write( Motor_pos);
                        __delay_ms(50);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else break;
            }
            Motor_pos = 0;
            ADC_s = 0;
            VAR_CW = LOW;   // M1 - Red LED
            VAR_CCW = LOW;  // M2 - Orange LED
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the *real* problem that you are trying to solve which makes you think you need to have an `if` condition after every line of code? Provide a higher level description of the requirements.

Comment: The Condition of While is start point to starting motor procedure. if this flag cleared the procedure have to terminate immediately and shut down the procedure. So after each line I have to check if this flag is Ture or NOT.

Comment: @Yunnosch. Sorry it's WHAT not WHY

Comment: Why do you need those inner `while` loops that have the same condition as their corresponding `if` checks? I suspect that just having everything handled directly in the `if` blocks would already be good enough

Comment: Okay let me make it more clear. I receive a Flag from UART to drive motor to a certain position So i built this function also I can receive termination flag from UART to STOP this operation. So i need something could stop the code inside the while or even If condition. hence that the Body take more than 2 sec so i can receive a message within this time.

Comment: So HOW could i check the condition of "If" or " While" while executing their bodies ?

Comment: To break; the Loop

Answer (score 1):

Your logic has several problems, and it is in no way obvious what the intent of your code is.  This is a reduction in the detail of your logic:

```
while (a || b) {
   if (a) {
      while (a) {
          do something a;
      }
      break;
   } else if (b) {
      while (b) {
          do something b;
      }
      break;
   } else {
      break;
   }
}
```

devolves into:

```
    if (a) {
        while (a) {
           do something a;
        }
    } else if (b) {
        while (b) {
           do something b;
        }
    }
```

So you really need to concentrate first on your simplifying steps, then the other.

Comment: this is good answer, but the feedback from the motor overshoots sometimes so i need to check if it within this range or exceed the other

Comment: If *kvp* is ever with +- 2 of *Motor_Pos*, how will that condition ever change?  It seems you only sample ADC_s when it is outside of that range?  Also, if overhead is your problem, why are you delaying for 50ms?   Shouldn't you have this code run on a 50ms event instead?  Relative delays are almost always wrong in reactive systems.